# Using dynamic memory allocation to add elements into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm supposed to write some code to ask the user to enter an array (1.3 4 5.2 16.3 9.99 7.21 4.5 7.43 11.21 12.5).

After that, I create a new array with a bigger size (double the size), copy all the elements from the old array to the new one, then ask the user to continue to enter 5 more elements to the new array: 1.5 4.5 9.5 16.5 7.5 11.5, and then print out the final array (15 elements).

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double* read_data(int& size) 
{
    int max = 10;         
    double* a = new double[max];  // allocated on heap
    size = 0;

    cout << "Enter the array: " << endl;
    while (cin >> a[size]) 
    {
        size++;
    }
    if (size >= max) 
    {
        double* temp = new double[max * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            temp[i] = a[i];       
        }
        delete[] a;             
        a = temp;   
        max = max * 2;  
    }
    return a;
}

int main () 
{
    int input1, input2, input3, input4, input5;

    int size = 0;
    double* arr = read_data(size);

    cout << "Please enter 5 more elements: " << endl;
    cin >> input1 >> input2 >> input3 >> input4 >> input5;
    arr[10] = input1;
    arr[11] = input2;
    arr[12] = input3;
    arr[13] = input4;
    arr[14] = input5;

    cout << "The final array is: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't let me enter 5 more elements and I don't know why.
Please help.

Comment: What does "It doesn't let me enter 5 more elements" mean?

Comment: I mean after the  cout << "Please enter 5 more elements: " << endl;

Comment: it skips the whole part below, and the output only has 10 elements

Comment: How does it know when to stop reading elements, in the first loop? `while (cin >> a[size]) {size++;}` will read as many elements as possible, and not care about the array size.

Comment: uhm i type q to quit ; __ ;

Comment: Then `cin >> a[size]` is going to fail because "q" isn't a number. And then `cin >> input1` is going to fail because "q" isn't a number. And then `cin >> input2` is going to fail because "q" isn't a number. And then `cin >> input3` is going to fail because "q" isn't a number. And I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: so am i supposed to use for loop? (Sorry in advance, this's my first programming course) ;; __ ;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are waiting for the input stream to enter a "false" state, that happens most visibly when there is an end of file character inputted to the stream.  So while inputting code to the terminal if you type in a -d you should see the code move onto the segment after the while loop.

To get away from this problem you will have to specify a limit to the array you are getting from the user so as to not overwrite memory out of bounds.

So change your code to this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double* read_data(int& size) 
{
    int max = 10;         
    double* a = new double[max];  // allocated on heap
    size = 0;

    cout << "Enter the array: " << endl;
    while (size < 10 && cin >> a[size]) 
    {
        size++;
    }
    if (size >= max) 
    {
        double* temp = new double[max * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            temp[i] = a[i];       
        }
        delete[] a;             
        a = temp;   
        max = max * 2;  
    }
    return a;
}

int main () 
{
    int input1, input2, input3, input4, input5;

    int size = 0;
    double* arr = read_data(size);

    cout << "Please enter 5 more elements: " << endl;
    cin >> input1 >> input2 >> input3 >> input4 >> input5;
    arr[10] = input1;
    arr[11] = input2;
    arr[12] = input3;
    arr[13] = input4;
    arr[14] = input5;

    cout << "The final array is: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    } cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how I added in the check for the size variable before the "`cin`" statement, this is referred to as short circuiting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  I do not consider this good style myself but I have included it here to show you how input statements are used in while loops and can cause bad behavior if you don't use it properly.

Also I added in a `cout << endl;` to flush the stream buffer so that the output does go to the screen before the `pause`

---

I just read what you said in the comments and I suggest the following code for the purpose to quit when a 'q' to exit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double* read_data(int& size) 
{
    int max = 10;         
    double* a = new double[max];  // allocated on heap
    size = 0;

    cout << "Enter the array: " << endl;
    char character;
    while (size < 10 && cin >> character) 
    {
        if (character == 'q') break;
        a[size] = character - '0';
        size++;
    }
    if (size >= max) 
    {
        double* temp = new double[max * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            temp[i] = a[i];       
        }
        delete[] a;             
        a = temp;   
        max = max * 2;  
    }
    return a;
}

int main () 
{

    int size = 0;
    double* arr = read_data(size);

    cout << "Please enter 5 more elements: " << endl;
    for (int i = size; i < size + 5; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    } 

    // add 5 to the size
    size += 5;

    cout << "The final array is: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    } cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh ok i see, so by adding size < 10, we can control the input '__ '

Comment: i upvoted but i havent had enough rep (15 reputation). When i had 15 rep, my vote for the answer will display :D

Comment: If the input is integer, everything's fine but hmm wondering why it doesn't work for floating number '___'

Comment: oh yea, i know why, change input type to double =))